# I get an error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." when running my query

Tags: sql

```
(SELECT
     CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(SECOND, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CONVERT(TIME, CONVERT(varchar(23), (CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(s, DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_sdate), DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_edate)) / 3600) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(5), 
        DATEDIFF(s, DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_sdate), DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_edate)) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(s, DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_sdate), DateAdd( HOUR, 0, f.Qc_edate)) % 60)),121),8))), 101),8)
 FROM
     TD_fileinfo f
 WHERE
     f.Qc_process = 1
     AND CAST(f.Qc_edate AS date) >= '02/04/2021'
     AND CAST(f.Qc_edate AS date) <= '02/04/2021')
```

I get error message below:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Please correctly format your code/error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Please show us  sample row(s) from TD_fileinfo so that we have data to replicate the problem.

Comment: check Qc_edate column values, may be some of row doesn't have proper value.